# 3D temperature distribution

Tags: matlab

First of all I am just a starter in Matlab, so the program is not optimized. For now I just want to get it running. This is a 3D heat problem with boundary conditions. Fixed temperature from the north, insulated from the bottom, and we have convection on the 4 surrounding sides with the same h. when I run it it does not give me the right convergences. I have the analytical and the solidworks approximations, so I know the results I get in Matlab are wrong. Could someone advise me please. 
Your help is appreciated.

```
%===Solution of the problem of 2D in the bookmarks:Case2a=====
clc;
close all;
clear all;

DX=0.01; % step size
DY=0.01;
DZ=0.01;
Lx= 0.6; %length along x-axis in cmn
Ly=0.4;   %length along y-axis
Lz=0.3;   %length along z-axis
Nx=Lx/DX+1;    %Number of nodes along x-axis
Nx=floor(Nx)+1; % I shouldn't add 1. I should get it automatically 
Ny=(Ly/DY+1);    %Number of nodes along y-axis
Ny=floor(Ny);
Nz=(Lz/DZ+1);
Nz=floor(Nz)+1;

K=2;
h=500;
T_inf=20;

X=0:DX:Lx;
Y=0:DY:Ly;
Z=0:DZ:Lz;

T=zeros(Nx,Ny,Nz);                                                            
% I added imaginary nodes outside then it gave me numbers

tol=1;
s=0; %s=2000 could be set as the maximum number of allowed iteration for 
example
err=1; 
T_old=1;

while err >=tol %&& s<2001
    s=s+1;

%------------boundary conditions------------------------------------------

%====North temperature (Boundary)
T(:,Ny,:)=90;  
%===South Boundary "insulation" ==============
for k=1:Nz
    for i=2:Nx-1
   T(i,1,k)=0.25*[2*T(i,2,k)+T(i-1,1,k)+T(i+1,1,k)];
  %T(i-1,1,k)=4* T(i,1,k)-2*T(i,2,k)-T(i+1,1,k);
    end
end
%================Back Boundary "Convection" ================
for j=2:Ny-1 %changed
    for i=2:Nx-1
  T(i,j,1)=0.5*K/(h*DX+2*K)*[2*T(i,j,2)+T(i-1,j,1)+T(i+1,j,1)+2*h*DX*T_inf/K];
    end
end
%================Front Boundary "Convection" ================
for j=2:Ny-1
    for i=2:Nx-1
  T(i,j,Nz)=0.5*K/(h*DX+2*K)*[2*T(i,j,Nz-1)+T(i-1,j,Nz-1)+T(i+1,j,Nz-1)+2*h*DX*T_inf/K];
    end
end

%================West Boundary "Convection" ================
for j=2:Ny-1
for k=2:Nz-1
  T(1,j,k)=0.5*K/(h*DX+2*K)*[2*T(2,j,k)+T(1,j,k-1)+T(1,j,k+1)+2*h*DX*T_inf/K];
    end
end
%================East Boundary "Convection" ================
for j=2:Ny-1
    for k=2:Nz-1
  T(Nx,j,k)=0.5*K/(h*DX+2*K)*[2*T(Nx-1,j,k)+T(Nx,j,k-1)+T(Nx,j,k+1)+2*h*DX*T_inf/K];
    end
end



% The interior nodes
for k = 2:Nz-1 % I think it needs to go loop by loop(pairs of loops)
    for j = 2:Ny-1
        for i=2:Nx-1
    T(i,j,k)=(1/6)*(T(i-1,j,k)+T(i+1,j,k)+T(i,j-1,k)+T(i,j+1,k)+T(i,j,k-1)+T(i,j,k+1));
        end
    end
end
err=max(max(abs(T-T_old)));
T_old=T;
end

T=rot90(T)
```

Comment: This question does not seem to be a programming question, but a physical one about heat transfer. It may be better to ask your question at https://physics.stackexchange.com/ or https://engineering.stackexchange.com.

Comment: Thank you for the advice. I will try to ask my question differently, so that it may make more sense. I think I know my problem, but I cannot fix it. the index i goes from 1 to Nx. south, back and front boundaries (check the corresponding loops in the code) need all to start from index i=1, however, the problem is that I cannot get i to start from 1, because then i-1 will give me an index of 0 which is not allowed in Matlab. Is there a way to fix that plz

Comment: Let `i` go from `2` to `Nx+1` (and make your vectors one element longer).

Comment: Note that if this is your only problem, you can simplify your question (to 1D?), which will make your it easier to answer and more useful to others. See [mcve].

Comment: I did the same exact problem in 2D and I did not have an issue with the indexing, but when I expanded the code to 3D, that's when the indexing prob rose.

Comment: I did T=zeros(Nx+1,Ny,Nz), and i=2:Nx like you suggested but I still get 0s on both sides of T(:,:,1) and T(:,:,4)

Comment: I guess you're not updating the points at (1,1,z)? (And the other three vertical edges of the volume)

Comment: Thank you Cris for spending the time to check this issue. Cris, I am not sure if you red my above comments in which I mentioned the indexing issue. I believe that if there is a way to set my indexing (i) to start from 1, this will probably fix the issue, but again putting i=1 will introduce  a 0 index along the x-axis which is not allowed in Matlab.

Comment: Cris, any idea on how to update the vertical edges you mentioned?

Comment: why does `T` have three indices some places and two in others?  (note this is both a matlab syntax question and a question about the solution method)

Comment: Thank you agentp. I updated the script to the most recent that I am running which has 3 indexes, however, I am still getting zeros at the four vertical edges of my matrix and that is my problem from the beginning.

Comment: `t(1,1,k)` is never set anywhere. Likely you need  separate loops to define the bc's on the edge nodes.

Comment: Thank you agentp for the insight. I added those edges separately as well as the corners and I got better results. in order for me to visualize the results in 3D (x,y,z) as nodes location and T as the temperature, is there a simpler way to plot it plz. I saw an online code and it was a very long one.

Answer (score 0):

The code I provided was giving me a 3d matrix with the vertical edges being all zeros. all I did was that I created 4 other loops for the vertical edges, but then I ended up with the bottom 4 corners having zero values. What i did was averaging the 3 neighboring temperatures of each corner. That way I have a 3d full matrix. Now it is working and I just have to figure out how to plot it. Thank you everyone for the suggestions.